# Is it possible to deauth 802.11ac (5GHz) clients with an 802.11a/b/g/n adapter?

Tags: wireless-networking, 802.11ac

Due to the lack of USB WIFI-adapters that support 802.11ac **and** packet injection, I'm wondering if it is possible to to use an 802.11a/b/g/n adapter to archieve the same goal on *ac*.

It is not intended to "hack" the client or connection, just to monitor (get MAC addresses of) the clients connected to the AP, and selectively deauth a specific client.

Answer (score -1):

No you can't, you can only deauthenticate 2.4GHz using a 2.4GHz radio.

The radio that is on the 5GHz it wont be "tuned" to 2.4 GHz to even see it.

Ideally you can just buy two separate adapters that can operate on each corresponding band.

Comment: user345866, you are wrong,actually 802.11a means it is a 5ghz adapter so it works. I had tried it before, it works!